# Need help,Screen didn't turn on after I change Activity's theme

Tags: android

I'm making my alarm app. There is  an Activity to show alarm infomation.
I want turn on the screen and unlock it. I wrote these code

**AlarmActivity.java:**

```
public class AlarmActivity extends Activity {
  ......
  void onCreate(Bundle bl) {
    .....
    final Window win = getWindow();
    win.requestFeature(android.view.Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);   
    win.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
               | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
               | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
               | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    setContentView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.alarm, null));
  }

  ......
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
{activity android:name="AlarmTaskActivity"
                android:excludeFromRecents="true"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar"
                android:launchMode="singleInstance"
                android:taskAffinity=""
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|navigation"/}
```

It's ok,but when I change
**android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar"**
to
**android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"**
the screen did not turn on nor unlock, I am really confused....

Can you please tell me how to make the screen turn on and unlock when I use "@android:style/Theme.Dialog"?

Thanks

by the way,I have android 2.0 in my test device.

Answer (score 0):

In order to activate the screen and force it to stay on, you need to use a `WakeLock.`  See the [documentation for more information.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html)  Changing the theme along won't cause the screen to wake up.  You'll need to use the `ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP` flag in order to do that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,I have already used the ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP flag. but I don't know why It is all ok when I use "android:style/Theme.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar" theme,but screen not turn on nor unlock when use "@android:style/Theme.Dialog"....